# Merging and comparing files using Linux command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a question about merging 2 data files.  The first file contains an IP address for the name of each server.  The second contains a data item and the associated IP address.

For output, I'd like to have the input of the second file, but with the mapped server name, looked up in the first file.

File_1:

```
10.1.1.1 server_1
10.1.1.2 server_2
10.1.1.3 server_3
```

File_2:

```
2  10.1.1.3
4  10.1.1.1
```

I need to figure out a command for getting the output below:

Output_file:

```
2 10.1.1.3  server_3
4 10.1.1.1  server_1
```

Comment: What is the size of the biggest file involved?

Comment: What have you considered?  Does the `join` command (and the `sort` command, and probably [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)) help?  Or you could use `awk`; or you could use Perl or Python or …

Comment: I think something got lost in the formatting.  What you're trying to do doesn't sound hard with basic command line utilities, I just can't really tell what you want.

Comment: The wording of your question is opaque.  You should probably split it into multiple sentences, maybe one describing the first input file, another describing the second, and a third describing the output.  Yes, we can just about see what you want, but the question could be (a lot) clearer.

Comment: Please review my edit.  If it does not match your intended question, please revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' file1 file2

2  10.1.1.3 server_3
4  10.1.1.1 server_1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,0,1.2 <(sort -k1 File_1) <(sort -k2 File_2)
```

Output:

```
4 10.1.1.1 server_1
2 10.1.1.3 server_3
```

Join on the first field of file 1, the second field of file 2, output the first field of file 2, the joining field, and the second field of file 1; take as input files the output of `sort -k1 File_1` and the output of `sort -k2 File_2`.

If you need the output sorted by the numeric value in the first column, pipe to `sort -k1n` (or `sort -n`).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your support as your mention command was very helpful